# Customizing Granite DS Actionscript code generation from Java classes

Tags: java, actionscript-3, groovy, code-generation, graniteds

I'm using [GraniteDS Actionscript code generation templates](http://www.graniteds.org/confluence/display/DOC20/3.+Gas3+Template+Language) that let's me take a Java object and convert it to an Actionscript class.

It's mainly used for BlazeDS Java to Flash communication but I'm adapting it to work with JSON webservices using XStream/JETTISON JSON.

Is it possible to use the Granite DS Groovy templates to inspect annotations on a Java class and use that to generate the code bindings?

For example I create an @XStreamAlias to shorten the class name when sent through JSON, but I need my Actionscript generated classes to support that as well.

```
package com.webwars.game;
@XStreamAlias("UnitStack")
public class UnitStack implements Serializable {
```

I want my Actionscript generated code to be:

```
package com.webwars.gameplatform.combat.pvp {

    [Bindable]
    [RemoteClass(alias="UnitStack")]
    public class UnitStack extends UnitStackBase {
```

Is this possible with the groovy templates?

I can't seem to find any documentation on what properties are available in the GraniteDS Groovy Template JavaType? The documentation listed on the GraniteDS site for JavaType goes to a broken Javadoc link.

For example in my bean.gsp can I do something like:

```
<%

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Use the XStreamAlias annotation as the classname

    def alias = jClass.qualifiedName;
    if (jClass.hasAnnotation("XStreamAlias)) {
      alias = jClass.getAnnotation("XStreamAlias");    
    } 

%>

[Bindable]
[RemoteClass(alias="${alias}")]
public class ${jClass.as3Type.name} extends ${jClass.as3Type.name}Base {<%
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I discovered source code for the JavaBean.java >> [JavaAbstractType.java](https://granite.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/granite/graniteds_builder/trunk/src/org/granite/generator/as3/reflect/JavaAbstractType.java)  which contains a method to get the Class:

```
public abstract class JavaAbstractType implements JavaType {
    public Class<?> getType() {
        return type;
    }
```

So in the Groovy **bean.gsp** template I modified it to support XStream aliased classes:

```
<%
    //////////////////////////////////
    /// Check if class has been Aliased by XStream
    def alias = jClass.qualifiedName;
    def actualClass = jClass.type;

    if (jClass.isAnnotationPresent(
                        com.thoughtworks.xstream.annotations.XStreamAlias.class)) {
        com.thoughtworks.xstream.annotations.XStreamAlias xstreamAlias = actualClass.getAnnotation(com.thoughtworks.xstream.annotations.XStreamAlias.class);
        alias = xstreamAlias.value();
    }
%>
[Bindable]
[RemoteClass(alias="${alias}")]
public class ${jClass.as3Type.name} extends ${jClass.as3Type.name}Base {<%
```